# Schechter function: plot

Tags: python, math

I have a Schechter function in dL:

```
def schechter(L):
    return (phistar/Lstar)*((L/Lstar)**alpha)*np.exp(-(L/Lstar))
```

but my problem is to plot this function in dlogL, so: how I do to pass from dL to dlogL?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your [mcve] and a description of your research?

Comment: Code formatting